# How to get missing values in a column with different value_counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, file, output

In a dataframe there is columns **Item Values**, **item weights**.

item weight has 1463 missing values

Say we used pandas

''' df['Item_Values'].value_counts()'''

which outputs:

'''

```
Fruits and Vegetables    1232
Snack Foods              1200
Household                 910
Frozen Foods              856
Dairy                     682
Canned                    649
Baking Goods              648
Health and Hygiene        520
Soft Drinks               445
Meat                      425
Breads                    251
Hard Drinks               214
Others                    169
Starchy Foods             148
Breakfast                 110
Seafood                    64
Name: Item_Type, dtype: int64'''
```

How to get missing values for each and every order?

e.g -

Fruits and Vegetables  -(no. of missing values??)

Snack Foods            -(no. of missing values??)
Household              -(no. of missing values??)

and so on...............

Comment: Where are there orders here?  Where are missing values?  You don't have nearly enough information here.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all rows with nans and apply your technique to this df[df['ColumnName'].isnull()].value_counts()